# Open Gimp in the same instance

Tags: gimp

After Ubuntu stock dist upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 and upgrade Gimp from 2.8 to 2.10 I can't open an image with Gimp in the same instance.

Simple call

```
$> gimp ./1.png
```

Or my bindsym

```
bindsym --release Print exec --no-startup-id "A=$(date +%s%N | cut -b1-13) && import -window root /raid/user/tmp/0images/$A.png && gimp /raid/user/tmp/0images/$A.png"$
```

I tried flatpak with the same result

```
$> flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP
```

In another case Gimp 2.8 works fine for all of this.

I didn't try Gimp 2.10 for Ubuntu 18.04.

The system: Ubuntu 20.04, Gimp GIMP 2.10.20, i3 4.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't think of anything smarter than to rename the `~/.gimp-2.8` folder

[image]

And it works fine from the current user context.

[image]